# Multiuser Editing with ArcGIS through LAN

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, editing

I am working on an ArcObjects application (C#), which is supposed to carry some customized editing operations, the database is ArcSDE based on Postgresql via (accessible via a LAN network).

One feature we're keen on is **multi-user-edition (MUE)** : multiple users should be able to edit the same layer (or objects in a layer) simultaneously.

The problem is that the application is frequently (once every week) overwhelmed (congested) thus disabling the MUE and leaving only one user to carry all the edition workload.

I am not very sure this is specifically related to the application (though there is a fair likelihood it is), so I had to wonder whether such an issue is experienced by users accessing a DB (via ArcSDE) and using ArcGIS desktop as an editor ; *** in other words, my hope is to get an idea about how solide is ArcGIS when it comes to MUE (how well does it deal with conflicts, scalability and data size when MUEing)***. (Heuristically, if it turns out that ArcGIS is infallible or near-infallible in this regard, I'll then know that I have to optimize somehow the application)

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Are you regularly reconciling and posting your edits, compressing the database, rebuilding indexes and statistics on the database, and those kinds of database maintenance tasks?  That is the single most important tool I've found in managing multi-user editing via ArcGIS Desktop.  You have to keep the back end managed or it will slow the client side down dramatically to the point of being unusable potentially... depending on your editing loads, number of users, etc...

Comment: Well, we regularly execute the compression to sort the back-end part of the application.